# MissingTemplateException from the Ajax request in CakePHP 3.10

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

We have a ctp page called 'pending' that will call a function ajaxpendingusers in our UsersController to list out all the pending users through an ajax request (getpendinglist) on page load. However, at times we get this MissingTemplateException stating the Template file "Users\json\pending.ctp" is missing although is not required. The ajax request (getpendinglist) is send to the UsersController/ajaxpendingusers function which is as below.

CakePHP: UsersController

```
public function ajaxpendingusers($role,$id){
    $this->disableAutoRender();
    $pendingList = $this->Users->getPendingUsers($role,$id);
    $this->response = $this->response->withStringBody(json_encode($pendingList));
    return $this->response;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function getpendinglist() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        cache: true,
        async: true,
        tryCount : 0,
        retryLimit : 10,
        url: '//' + window.location.host + '/users/ajaxpendingusers.json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }, 
        error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
           console.log(textStatus);
           console.log(errorThrown);
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

```
Error: [Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException] Template file "Users\json\pending.ctp" is missing. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\View.php:1605)
```

We do not have a Users\json\pending.ctp but we have Users\pending.ctp in our Template folder. In additional, we do not have Users\json\ajaxpendingusers.ctp since we have used disableAutoRender in the ajaxpendingusers function. This error happens randomly. Could anybody please help to figure out why do we get the MissingTemplateException and how to catch it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That error most likely does not belong to that action, there's almost 0 chance that it would only break sometimes, and on top of that change to a template name that doesn't match the action name. The error, is related to either the action named `pending()`, or to an action that explicitly configures the view builder or calls `render()` to render the `pending` template. Check the stacktrace that belongs to that error, it might show you which controller/action is being involved.

Comment: have some questions for you:
why the url param start with `//` ? 
why this url ends with `.json` ?
if you want to send an ajax request to the method/action called ajaxpendingusers() from UsersController.php you should use `'/users/ajaxpendingusers'` as url.
Also you should validate the type of request method using `$this->request->is('ajax')` in the controller

Comment: @SebástianSperandio thanks you for the pointer. As code was from over the years, I believe it could be from the previous versions of CakePHP. We have updated the url and removed .json from the url.

Comment: @EssEss Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: Haven't got the error again so far. On further digging, we realised that the error was from the previous Ajax request that deletes a record listed in the page. The delete function was not returning the Ajax response properly.